# Object calculating validation C#

Tags: c#, object

My goal is to make this program to take a number of pizzas and types of pizzas and count how much they cost. I decided to go with an object solution. The problem is it doesn't calculate it and it lets the program run even when The fields are empty. I literally have no idea why it doesn't calculate it. I'm also new to objects so there may be some logical mistakes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Assignment_2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void OrderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double withTax = 0;
            double tax = 0;
            double subTotal = 0;
            var pizzas = new Pizza[3];
            if(ValidateAndDeclareQuantities())
            {
                pizzas = Declare();
                subTotal = CalcSubTotal(pizzas);
                tax = CalcTax(pizzas);
                withTax = CalcWithTax(pizzas);
            }

        }
        bool ValidateAndDeclareQuantities()
        {
            var combolist = new List<ComboBox>();
            combolist.Add(comboBox1);
            combolist.Add(comboBox2);
        combolist.Add(comboBox3);
        var textboxlist = new List<TextBox>();
        textboxlist.Add(Quantity1);
        textboxlist.Add(Quantity2);
        textboxlist.Add(Quantity3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if (combolist[i].Text == "Cheese" || combolist[i].Text ==     "Vegetable" || combolist[i].Text == "Meat")
            { }
            else combolist[i].Text = "Wrong input";
        }
        int[] Quantities = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(textboxlist[i].Text, out     Quantities[i])&&textboxlist[i].Text!=null)
            { }
            else { textboxlist[i].Text = "Wrong input"; }
        }
        return true;
    }

    Pizza[] Declare()
    {
        var pizzas = new Pizza[3];
        string type;
        int price;
        type = comboBox1.Text;
        price = int.Parse(Quantity1.Text);
        Pizza pizza1 = new Pizza(type, price);
        pizzas[0] = pizza1;

        type = comboBox2.Text;
        price = int.Parse(Quantity2.Text);
        Pizza pizza2 = new Pizza(type, price);
        pizzas[1] = pizza2;

        type = comboBox3.Text;
        price = int.Parse(Quantity3.Text);
        Pizza pizza3 = new Pizza(type, price);
        pizzas[2] = pizza3;

        return pizzas;
    }

    double CalcSubTotal(Pizza[] pizzas)
    {
        double subTotal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            subTotal += pizzas[i].Price;
        }
        return subTotal;
    }

    double CalcTax(Pizza[] pizzas)
    {
        double tax = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            tax += pizzas[i].Tax;
        }
        return tax;
    }

    double CalcWithTax(Pizza[] pizzas)
    {
        double withTax = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            withTax += pizzas[i].WithTax;
        }
        return withTax;
    }

    void WriteOut(double subTotal, double tax, double withTax)
    {
        lblSubTotal.Text = "" + subTotal;
        lblTax.Text = "" + tax;
        lblTotal.Text = "" + withTax;
    }

    }
}
```

And the class:
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

```
namespace Assignment_2
{
class Pizza
{
    string type;
    int quantity;
    public double Price;
    public double SubTotal;
    public double Tax;
    public double WithTax;
    public Pizza(string type, int quantity)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        FindPrice();
        CalcSubTotal();
        CalcTax();
        CalcWithTax();
    }
    private void FindPrice()
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case "Cheese":
                Price = 9.95;
                break;
            case "Vegetables":
                Price = 10.95;
                break;
            case "Meat":
                Price = 11.95;
                break;
        }
    }
    private void CalcSubTotal()
    {
        SubTotal = Price * quantity;
    }
    private void CalcTax()
    {
        Tax = SubTotal * 0.13;
    }
    private void CalcWithTax()
    {
       WithTax = SubTotal + Tax;
    }
}
}
```

[Solution form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbdTr.png)

Comment: Sorry to say .. but you need to rethink the whole setup here. At least the while *validate* - *declare* part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answers:

- `ValidateAndDeclareQuantities` never returns `false`. It should (probably) return false when you set "Wrong Input".
- (Minor) int[] Quantities = new int[3]; is never used, aside from writing to it.
- (Minor) `var pizzas = new Pizza[3];` is also never used. It just gets overwritten by Declare a few lines later. `Pizza[] pizzas=null;` or just `Pizza[] pizzas;` is a better alternative. Not the greatest structure here though.
- (Minor) Your variable called `price` in `Declare` is poorly named as it appears to actually be quantity. Things like this easily throw people off.
- WriteOut is never called. `withTax`, `tax` and `subTotal` in `OrderButton_Click` are *probably* being computed correctly, but the values aren't being outputted.

**The longer answer**

It's a bit on the messy side! I appreciate that it's just a learning thing - we've all been there - but good code hygiene is just as important (if not more important) than the structure of the language.

**UX:** Don't overwrite what the user entered - specifically, don't replace the textbox input with "wrong input"; That's better off going on some other label. I would imagine you've already felt how weird this kind of experience is whilst testing the code.

**Named things that don't need a specific class:** Like a cheese pizza and a ham one. Enums are your friend! Use them instead of strings like "Cheese":

```
public enum PizzaType{
    Cheese,
    Tomato
}
```

Using enums in this way helps avoid the wonderful world of pain that is unexpected capitalisation and it's considerably faster too. CheEse pizza anyone?

**Repetition:** Large portions of your code are repetitive too; You'll want to practice avoiding it as much as you can. ('DRY'/ 'Don't Repeat Yourself'). A little forward planning helps massively. Everybody has preferences on code structure; mine here would be a separate "Pizza displayer" class which holds a quantity input box and does the validation too.

**Junk:** Slightly related to the above, you're creating a bunch of Lists and arrays which get created each time the function is called and then are just chucked out. Create a single array of some more abstract type (like an array of "Pizza displayers") and keep that array as a property on the Form. It's minor here, but being more aware of how much trash your program creates helps make your code go faster.

**Notes on floats:** You should never, *ever* use float/ double for money. Use decimal instead, or just do everything in pennies. Floating points aren't precise and you'll hit a rounding issue sooner or later.

Comment: In my defence: I thought I have to tell the Array how many elements are in it when declaring. Thanks for the help! All works just fine now. I did the error reports in the text boxes because the user will have to change it anyway so why create more labels. I'll rewrite the code again. Don't quite understand the concept of objects yet. I know the theory not how to use them well in practice.
Anyway, Thanks!

Comment: @alex3wielki no problem! You're right about arrays, but an array is also an object - each time you do "new {something}" you're creating an entirely new object, *unless it's a struct*. So for example, `var pizzas = new Pizza[3];` and inside declare you've got `new Pizza[3];` a second time - that's two entirely different objects; the first one goes unused :)